# How do I create a simple scene on a game using Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm running the main default class that is created from the template of a Monogame project, normally I put everything there and just call my classes and that work for a simple game

Now, I want to have scenes, how do I manage that??

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: You might get better responses to this type of question on the [MonoGame Community forums](http://community.monogame.net/)

Comment: MonoGame doesn't provide a built-in `Scene` class - you need to make your own.